# MongoDB Sum the Frequency that a Field Value Exists with the Value of Another Field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

I have a database that looks like:

```
spider_results = [
    
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "345g435f543f"
    },
    "url": "localhost:8080/path1/",
    "proxy": {
        "proxy": "196.0.1.1:1500",
        "protocol": "http",
    },
    "success": false,
},

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "14544gtf543f"
    },
    "url": "localhost:8080/path2/",
    "proxy": {
        "proxy": "196.0.1.1:1500",
        "protocol": "http",
    },
    "success": true,
},

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "t4rw4rww4r"
    },
    "url": "localhost:8080/path3/",
    "proxy": {
        "proxy": "192.168.255.255:1500",
        "protocol": "http",
    },
    "success": true,
},

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "ferfrw4456"
    },
    "url": "localhost:8080/path4/",
    "proxy": {
        "proxy": "192.168.255.255:1500",
        "protocol": "http",
    },
    "success": true,
},

]
```

My goal is to count the number of times that each proxy was/wasn't "success." The result would look like:

```
196.0.1.1:1500         --> success:true  = 1
196.0.1.1:1500         --> success:false = 1
192.168.255.255:1500   --> success:true  = 2
192.168.255.255:1500   --> success:false = 0
```

I've been running individual queries like

```
{"proxy.proxy": "192.168.255.255:1500", success: true}

{"proxy.proxy": "192.168.255.255:1500", success: false}
```

But as the number of proxies is increasing, this is obviously not sufficient. There is a very good chance I'm not Googling the correct search query for my question, because I've yet to find anyone who is attempting the same type of search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it this way:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        proxy: "$proxy.proxy",
        success: "$success"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This is the result for this query:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "proxy": "196.0.1.1:1500",
      "success": true
    },
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "proxy": "196.0.1.1:1500",
      "success": false
    },
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "proxy": "192.168.255.255:1500",
      "success": true
    },
    "count": 2
  }
]
```

PS: This counts number of success of each proxy that's inside your db, and output nothing if there's no success value for that proxy; for example this case won't be output **192.168.255.255:1500   --> success:false = 0**

You can try it out [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_3MGfW7CDpM)

Comment: Very succinct, brilliant, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Query

- we need to group by proxy and count 2 fields  `true-success`, and `false-success` that we don't have, but we can create them based on success field that we already have.

  - `success : true` becomes {"true-count": 1, "false-count": 0}
  - `success : false` becomes {"true-count": 0, "false-count": 1}
    And now we have those 2 fields that we need in each document.
- `set` to add this extra fields
- `group` and `count` the true and the false success
- make the 2 fields an array and unwind (to separate the fields in different documents)
- `project` to fix the structure

*produces the expected output, with the data that didn't exist in the db, like in your example.

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70110218-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
    {"success": 
      {"$cond": 
        ["$success",
          {"true-count": 1, "false-count": 0},
          {"true-count": 0, "false-count": 1}]}}},
  {"$group": 
    {"_id": "$proxy.proxy",
      "true-count": {"$sum": "$success.true-count"},
      "false-count": {"$sum": "$success.false-count"}}},
  {"$set": 
    {"success": 
      [{"count": "$true-count", "success": true},
       {"count": "$false-count", "success": false}]}},
  {"$unwind": {"path": "$success"}},
  {"$project": 
    {"_id": 0,
      "proxy": "$_id",
      "count": "$success.count",
      "success": "$success.success"}}])
```